# Flatten nested json in Hiveql

Tags: sql, json, hive, bigdata, hue

I am trying to parse nested json files into a hive table. The nested json files are present in a hdfs path. I know that the parsing can be done in Python and then a table can be created on top of the parsed file.

But I want to explore if there is a way to parse It directly in HUE.

2 of the JSON files are given below:

```
{"success":true,"requestId":"rrt-0fc220890f83f585a-b-ea-9810-141442877-1","results":{"bin":"700632138","matchedBusiness":{"bin":"700632138","reliabilityCode":100,"businessName":"RANDOM BUSINESS","phone":"+1----------","address": "street":"xxx","city":"yyy","state":"zz","zip":"12345","zipExtension":"1234"},"numberOfTradelines":5,"financialStatementIndicator":false,"keyFactsIndicator":true,"inquiryIndicator":false,"bankDataIndicator":false,"governmentDataIndicator":false,"executiveSummaryIndicator":false,"uccIndicator":true,"businessGeocode":{"latitudeLongitudeLevel":"Roof Top Level","latitude":12.3456,"longitude":-23.34567,"msaCode":"8000","censusBlkGrpCode":"1","censusTractCode":"800202","cottageIndicator":false,"congressionalDistrictCode":"01","dateLastReported":"2023-05-06"}},"socialAttributes":{"RAT001":"-1.00","RAT002":"-100.00","RAT003":"-1.00","RAT004":"-100.00","RAT005":"4.00","RAT006":"0.00","RAT007":"4.00","RAT008":"0.00","RAT009":"-1.00","RAT010":"-1.00","RAT011":"-1.00","RAT012":"-100.00","RAT013":"-100.00","RAT014":"-100.00","RAT015":"-1.00","RAT016":"-1.00","RAT017":"-1.00","RAT018":"-1.00","RVW001":"0.00","RVW002":"0.00","RVW003":"0.17","RVW004":"0.08","RVW005":"-1.00","RVW006":"0.00","RVW007":"0.00","RVW008":"-100.00","RVW009":"-0.45","RVW010":"-0.30","RVW011":"0.00","RVW012":"-1.00","RVW013":"0.00","RVW019":"0.00","RVW014":"-1.00","RVW015":"-1.00","RVW016":"-1.00","RVW017":"-1.00","REC002":"168.00","REC001":"168.00","BTA001":"3.394","BTA002":"3.581","BTA003":"3.661","BTA004":"3.770","BTA005":"0.380","BTA006":"0.333","BTA007":"0.312","BTA008":"0.283","BTA009":"-1.000","BTA010":"-1.000","BTA011":"1.093","BTA012":"1.061","BTA013":"0.000","BTA014":"0.000","BTA015":"0.534","BTA016":"0.294","FRM001":"2","FRM008":"2","FRM009":"5","FRM010":"0","FRM011":"7","FRM012":"1","FRM013":"1","FRM014":"0","FRM015":"0","FRM016":"0","GRG002":"0.1652","GRG001":"0.1652","BCR001":["Sports Bars","Breakfast & Brunch"],"BCR003":"0.21264367816091953","BCR007":"0.21621621621621623","BCR005":"0.2129032258064516","BCR002":"0.21068249258160238","BCR006":"0.20889662249587293","BCR004":"0.20847555299437032","FRM002":"full_bar","FRM003":"NA","RVW018":"15","FRM006":"No","FRM007":"NA","FRM004":"lot"],"SMIKEY":"9f1cb4992999c6391adcdfd619cfc964de4c7c0f5c3f8f2323ab36f741939ec6"},"modelOutput":{"score":81,"scoreFactors":[132,125,128]}}} 


{"success":true,"requestId":"rrt-0fc220890f83f585a-b-ea-9811-141442925-1","results":{"bin":"701115259","matchedBusiness":"bin":"701115259","reliabilityCode":93,"businessName":"RANDOM BUSINESS 2","phone":"+1+++++++++++++","address":{"street":"qwerrtyuio","city":"zzz","state":"xx","zip":"09876","zipExtension":"3725"},"numberOfTradelines":4,"financialStatementIndicator":false,"keyFactsIndicator":true,"inquiryIndicator":false,"bankDataIndicator":false,"governmentDataIndicator":false,"executiveSummaryIndicator":false,"uccIndicator":true,"matchingNameAndAddress":{"businessName":"RANDOM 3","address":"street":"poiutruuwn","city":"aaaa","state":"ssss","zip":"56789"}},"businessGeocode":{"latitudeLongitudeLevel":"Roof Top level","latitude":12.3456678,"longitude":-45.4533,"msaCode":"1120","censusBlkGrpCode":"1","censusTractCode":"354100","cottageIndicator":false,"congressionalDistrictCode":"05","dateLastReported":"2020-12-15"}},"socialAttributes":null,"modelOutput":null}}
```

These are nested json. So, is it possible to possible to create columns for each field? Use key-value for the column. Ex: address.street, address.City and so on. If there are no values for a given field, then that has be to appended as NULL in the table.

I was able to parse the fields using jsonSERDE, but not able to flatten it and create a new column for the nested JSON part.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.